# can I add something in the middle of a pie chart by using fl-chart package?

Tags: flutter, graph, package, fl-chart

How to add an image / icon or any object in the middle of a  pie chart in fl_chart package for flutter ?

I want to make this: [Iwant to have the running man!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxjci.png)

Comment: any idea about making  section's border curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try stack and use icon on top of pie and use alignment or padding to get icon in middle like :

```
 Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        // icon, svg, image
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.add),
                        ),
                        your_fl_widget(),
                      ],
                    )
```

Comment: does this work ?

Comment: yes you can try it

Answer (score 1):

you can't do this, this is the response from the creator of fl_chart:

> Hi. At the moment there is no possibility to support Widgets in the
> title. (I hope we can implement it in the future)
>
> As a workaround, you can have an icon font to implement icons instead
> of texsts. https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/issues/880